# How to initialize an ObservableList?

Tags: java

I have looked everywhere web, oracle java documents but can't find anything. How can I initialize a ObservableList.

```
ObservableList<Double> list;
```

If I do this I get this error

> The local variable characters may not have been initialized

Until I found the answer on my own which I couldn't, I was doing this to initialize ObservableList

```
Polyline polyline = new Polyline();
ObservableList<Double> list = polyline.getPoints();
list.add(1.0);
```

But now I have to use String instead of Double and this doesn't work, so what is the solution to this.

Comment: Assuming we are talking about Java FX [ObservableList](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html), that is an interface. So you need one of its implementations to initialize a variable of that type.

Comment: So I looked up for FXCollections and found the solution-- ObservableList<Character> characters = FXCollections.observableArrayList('A');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize a variable when you assign it the first time.

`Type variable;` only declares the variable, but leaves it unassigned. `String s;` will fail in the same way when used. `String s = "abc";` assigns a value to the variable (i.e. initializes it).

Another way to put it: `String s;` does *not* create a string, but only tells the compiler: `s` will eventually point to a string instance, but right now it does not point anywhere.

If you are asking how to create a new instance of type ObservableList, then the factory methods in [`FXCollections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html) will be a good starting point